# How to calculate an average with complex conditions in excel

Tags: excel

I will explain this the best I can.

I have a data sheet extracted with SQL. My goal is to calculate the average of certain cells in a column. There is a condition that the row which the cell is in contains a specific letter such as "B".

I'm dealing with building permits and they all have an id with the form: "12-3456-12-B". The letter resembles the type of permit and that's how I want to divide my averages. In the column I wish to extract the averages from is a percentage that resembles the degree of repair on the said permit.

So what I want is to have an average degree of repairs on individual permit types.

On a logical perspective: "Use the value if Cell B in current row contains i.e. "-B""

Cheers!

Comment: Why not do all the calculations in SQL, then extract?

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with SQL, but i believe this database does not offer the possibility. Also I'm not the one extracting the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the IDs are in column `B` and the %s in column `C` this is quite simple using `AVERAGEIF` function in Excel with a `"wildcard"`, e.g.

`=AVERAGEIF(B:B,"*B",C:C)`

That formula averages column C where the column B entry on the same row ends with "B"

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Any specific problems?

From my point of view you've basically got two choices:

1) You use Excel formulas

2) You use VBA (recommended)

Using option 1 can be done several ways. The easiest is probably using a new column for each permit type and then just using simple `IF` formulas in there to get the value in case the `RIGHT(yourCell, 1)` is B or C or whatever. Then you do a `COUNTIF` to get the number of entries in that column which will enable you to calculate the average of the columns values.

Another way would be via `VLOOKUP`. Using this you can build up your own matrix and then calculate the averages (I would prefer this one over the approach above).

Now for option 2 (VBA):

This won't bloat up your actual excel sheet, which is a big plus imho. Get an array for every permit type and just use a simple loop to parse every row (with content) in the sheet and add the degree of repair value to the appropriate array. Once finished just parse each array, calculate your averages and write them back into the sheet to some nice result table.

Comment: I might have the solution in the first answer, but I will give this a go as well. Thanks!